# Can Orangedox tell me which individuals opened my files, not just how many people did?

Tags: orangedox

I just started using Orangedox, and I can't tell if it will do what I want or not. Can Orangedox tell me which individuals opened my files, not just how many people did?

Answer (score 1):

[Orangedox](http://orangedox.com/dropbox) can tell you who opened your files.  Unlike Dropbox you can create multiple links to each file or folder that can be shared, simply create a new share link to the file using Orangedox then share it with each individual, this way you can know who is opening/reading your documents.

If you're using Gmail you can [signup for our Gmail plugin](http://orangedox.com/gmail) and when you send Dropbox files via email we'll notify you when the recipient reads/downloads the attachment.

One thing to keep in mind is that if your Orangedox link is shared with a wide audience we don't be able to tell you who exactly opened it. We will be adding features later this year that will tell you how many unique people have been reading/downloading your documents, but we won't be able to tell you exactly who they are

---

Editor's note: Chad Brown is the [CEO and Co-Founder of Orangedox](https://www.orangedox.com/about/)

Comment: "We" as in you're from the company? You should at least disclose that fact in the answer and/or your profile